# What does a 'logical AND' in an analog signalflow mean?

Tags: analog, adc, circuit-design

The link aboves shows the functionality of an AD-Converter based on a sawtooth signal.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-Digital-Umsetzer#/media/File:Single_slope_dac.png

As it is asked in the topic, what is the function of the &-Box (e.g. behind the both operational amplifiers)? I thought it is a mixer, but I'm not sure and it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The K1 and K2 are comparators. You can think of them either returning a 0 when the negative input has a greater voltage than the positive one, and 1 in the opposite case.

This kind of notation is also pretty common in DC-DC converter chip datasheets as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

K1 and K2 are comparators, which will convert the analog (continous) input signal into a discrete signal depending on its level in respect to the sawtooth generator (Ur).

From there on it's all a digital circuit